# Google Sheet Query Function giving #NAME? error

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from another sheet called "NewData" using the Query function. I'm getting a #NAME? error.

> > =query(NewData!A1:H,
> > "select B,sum(C)
> > group by B")

I do not think there's any spelling mistakes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there are spelling mistakes. Check for spaces at the end of sheet name.

Comment: I think misspelling sheet name would give #REF! error. Hover over cell with error, it should show full error, what does it say?